# Set Background Camera behind UILabels

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avcapturesession, viewdidload

I have been trying for very long and could not get it to work out but basically I would like to display the live camera feed in the background behind my labels and buttons. Here is the code I am working with to make the camera appear

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice  defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    [session addInput:input];

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

    [self.view addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.view];

    [session startRunning];

}
```

I do not know how to place it behind the labels on the view did load. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `[self.view.layer sendSubviewToBack:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];` try to set view in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add the view in background by using `sendSubviewToBack`

For more detail you can check [Apple AVCam Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

> sendSubviewToBack:
>   Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];
[session startRunning];
```

OR

```
[[self.view superView] insertSubview:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer belowSubview:self.view];
```

Comment: when I add this code I get an error that says "No visible @interface for 'CALayer' declares the selector 'sendSublayerToBack:'" I am only implementing the AVCapture session in the view did load so I do not have it declared anywhere else

Comment: Now im getting No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'addSublayer:' and Incompatible pointer types sending 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *' to parameter of type 'UIView * _Nonnull' I also tried connecting the view in my .h file and labeled it cameraview but when I ran the app it crashed this is a pain! I thank you for your help as well

Comment: @spel `[self.view addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.view];` check my updated ans i forgot to add :newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.view now check with my latest ans

Comment: now the .view that was added is getting "Property 'view' not found on object of type 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer " for both self.view's

Comment: you are doing something wrong can you i see your full source code ?

Comment: I put it in the question and I know I am I have been struggling for a day on it! do you need my .h as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101443/discussion-between-mayank-patel-and-spel).